# javafx tableview tablemodel connection

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, tablemodel

I would like to connect my javafx tableview to my table model's data to display in the view.

I am receiving an error:

```
incompatible types: WorkoutTableModel cannot be converted to ObservableList
```

Any insight or suggestions are greatly appreciated. 
I am also getting the error when trying to convert to ObservableList:

```
incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: Workout
    lower bounds: WorkoutTableModel
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method <E>observableArrayList(E...)

The type of <E>observableArrayList(E...) is erroneous
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method <E>observableArrayList(E...)
```

Thanks!

table model:

```
package myworkouts.presentation;

import myworkouts.domain.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class WorkoutTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private String[] columnNames = {"Date", "Route", "Distance", "Time"};

private List<Workout> workouts = new LinkedList<Workout>();

public void setWorkouts(List<Workout> workouts) {
    this.workouts = workouts;
}    

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return workouts.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    Workout workout = workouts.get(row);
    switch (column) {
        case 0:
            return workout.getDate();
        case 1:
            return workout.getRoute();
        case 2:
            return workout.getDistance();
        case 3:
            return workout.getTime();
    }
    return "";
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return columnNames[column];
    }
}
```

mainUI snippit:

```
public class MainUI extends Application {

private Account account = null;

private WorkoutTableModel model = new WorkoutTableModel();

final ObservableList<Workout> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(model);

public void setAccount(Account account) {
    this.account = account;
}


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

    primaryStage.setTitle("Workout CRUD form JavaFX Application");

    TableView workoutsTbl = new TableView(); 
    workoutsTbl.setEditable(true);

    workoutsTbl.setItems(model);

    // Add workoutsTbl header

    Text headerLabel = new Text("Workouts");

    headerLabel.getStyleClass().add("header");

    // add workoutsTbl column labels
    TableColumn dateCol = new TableColumn("Date");
    TableColumn routeCol = new TableColumn("Route");
    TableColumn distanceCol = new TableColumn("Distance");
    TableColumn timeCol = new TableColumn("Time");     

    workoutsTbl.getColumns().addAll(dateCol, routeCol, distanceCol, timeCol);      
    workoutsTbl.autosize();

    VBox vbox  = new VBox(10);
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10,5,5,10));

    // Create the registration form grid pane
    GridPane gridPane = createWorkoutsFormPane();
    //gridPane.add(workoutsTbl,1,10,2,5);
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(headerLabel,workoutsTbl,gridPane);

    // Add UI controls to the registration form grid pane
    addUIControls(gridPane);
    // Create a scene with registration form grid pane as the root node
    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 520, 500);
    // Set the scene in primary stage   
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    scene.getStylesheets().add
        (MainUI.class.getResource("Login.css").toExternalForm());  

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: You're confusing Swing and JavaFX. These are two completely different toolkits.

Comment: This is true. I just noticed that. How would I update the model to accommodate the JavaFX UI?

Comment: That's too broad a question. Look at some tutorials and ask a specific question if you can't make it work. The [makery tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part2/) is very popular

Comment: Use `data` as items list and set the `cellValueFactory`s to return the appropriate properies. Assuming the getters are public `PropertyValueFactory` with constructor parameters `"date"`, `"route"`, `"distance"` and `"time"`. But do yourself a favor and add type parameters to the `TableView` and the `TableColumn`s. Otherwise some of the type checks the compiler could are impossible and would result in exceptions at runtime instead which is harder to debug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

final ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(model);

A Swing AbstractTableModel is not a List-type thing. Look at it's declaration and see what it implements. It's not List.